# Extending Number prototype in typescript using wrong 'this' pointer

Tags: typescript

There is some code in my app that extends the Number prototype in JavaScript for a safer division operator, like this:

```
_.extend(Number.prototype, {
    divide: (denominator, default_val) => {
        var ret_val;
        if (is_numeric(denominator) && denominator !== 0) {
            ret_val = this / denominator;
        } else {
            ret_val = default_val || 0;
        }
        return ret_val;
    }
}
```

It's arguably not proper to do this code, but it always worked as expected.

I'm converting my app to TypeScript (which I'm just learning), and when this code is transpiled to JavaScript, it comes out like this:

```
_.extend(Number.prototype, {
    divide: function (denominator, default_val) {
        var ret_val;
        if (is_numeric(denominator) && denominator !== 0) {
            ret_val = _this / denominator;
        }
        else {
            ret_val = default_val || 0;
        }
        return ret_val;
    }
}
```

Note that *this* is now *_this*.  _this is not a numeric value (it's the window), and the division is returning NaN.

"this" is the Number, "_this" is window.

Is this expected?  Is there some way to access to the number value correctly in the original TypeScript code?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function expression:

```
_.extend(Number.prototype, {
    divide: function(denominator, default_val) {
        var ret_val;
        if (is_numeric(denominator) && denominator !== 0) {
            ret_val = this / denominator;
        } else {
            ret_val = default_val || 0;
        }
        return ret_val;
    }
}
```

Function expressions don't lexically bind the `this` value.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I should not have been so quick to use the fancier lambda notation.  Thank you!

Comment: TSLint: Calls to '_.extend' are not allowed.(ban)